# Add To Existing Macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I see similar questions on the forum about adding to macros, but none of them solved the issue for me.

Right now when I run the macro below, it creates a new workbook with only one sheet in it.  I need it to create 3 sheets in the new workbook instead of 1.  Please help

```
Sub RunSupplierOTD()
'
' RunSupplierOTD Macro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    Range("H49").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Vendor Name"
    Range("I49").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    Range("A49:S49").Select
    Range("S49").Activate
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$49:$S$177").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("#" _
        , "12633", "79204", "79247", "79371", "79479", "79498", "79583", "IC3000"), Operator _
        :=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Comment: Record adding a sheet and add that code twice would be my advice

Comment: Would I then just copy the whole macro to the existing one or would i just copy part of the code and paste it to the existing one? Here is the new one.  Which part do I copy and where do I paste?              Sub AddNewSheet()
'
' AddNewSheet Macro
'

'
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End Sub

Comment: this bit..
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) will add a new sheet to the end of the workbook each time you run it. So if you added it twice at the end of your macro your workbook will have 2 more sheets. Btw, I dont think your macro actually creates a workbook. In fact, I think you could remmove all the code above "ActiveSheet.Range("$A$49:$S$177")" and this would still do the same thing essentially.

Comment: Yes you are right.  That was the wrong macro.  But it was similar.  What you suggested worked.  Please post it, so I can give you credit.

Comment: Okay, now that it creates sheet2 for me.  Can I have it default back to sheet1 instead of landing on sheet2 like it is doing now

Answer (score 1):

One answer to the OPs question of how to add a sheet to a workbook in Excel VBA is to use the following code:

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

One thing I would say is that recording macros in Excel produces loads and loads of unnecessary code. One thing that it teaches you though is how to do certain things. In the comments of the question the OP asks a very common question for people beginning in Excel VBA, namely how to select objects such as sheets and cells. There are many ways to do this, each using different methods such as "Application.Goto".

A good reference can be found at the link below and I would recommend anyone looking to get started in Excel VBA to read this link

http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/291308

as well as recording macros and examining the resulting code.

Hth, O